# External HD mounts to different /media location on every reboot and partialy at that

Tags: mount, external-hdd

The files graphical app always shows my external drive consistently under "Other Location". The external driver is called dropbox.

[image]

From the terminal, I get 4 mounts for this hd.

```
dir /media/john
dropbox  dropbox1  dropbox2  dropbox3
```

And even more strange, I get different views on each of these 4 mounts.

```
john@john-ubuntu:~$ dir /media/john/dropbox3/transcription_db
tensorboard_logs
john@john-ubuntu:~$ dir /media/john/dropbox2/transcription_db
run_results  tensorboard_logs
john@john-ubuntu:~$ dir /media/john/dropbox1/transcription_db
crops_sets
john@john-ubuntu:~$ dir /media/john/dropbox/transcription_db
crops_sets
```

Most of the time, one of these contains the full list of files, but sometimes each captures only a partial view.

Is there a way to fix where the external hard drive gets installed?

Other info :

```
john@john-ubuntu:~$ cat /etc/fstab
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=eae8cd57-5861-41df-95ae-8e5e79a2c6b2 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
/swapfile                                 none            swap    sw              0       0
```

Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS

```
sudo fdisk -l
....
Disk /dev/sdb: 3.7 TiB, 4000787030016 bytes, 7814037168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 27569B50-D174-424A-A7BF-4A0E7353C4D9

Device     Start        End    Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sdb1   2048 7814035455 7814033408  3.7T Microsoft basic data
```

Another post suggested this, but it does not work

```
sudo mount -t ntfs /dev/sdb1 /media
Mount is denied because the NTFS volume is already exclusively opened.
The volume may be already mounted, or another software may use it which
could be identified for example by the help of the 'fuser' command.
```

I just rebooted, looked at the drive with "Files" graphical app. All was good there as usual. In the terminal, I now have a 4th mount and this one has all the content.

```
dir /media/john/dropbox4/transcription_db
crops_sets  db\ backups  run_results  tensorboard_logs  user_files


john@john-ubuntu:~$ mount | grep /dev/sdb1
/dev/sdb1 on /media/john/dropbox4 type fuseblk (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,default_permissions,allow_other,blksize=4096,uhelper=udisks2)
```

disk graphical app -> Additional partion options -> Edit mount options
[image]

I tried making the following entry to fstab and the system failed to boot:
[image]

[image]

Comment: You could try with Disks->options->Mount options

Comment: The drive is not mounted via fstab, what does `mount | grep /dev/sdb1` show?

Comment: /dev/sdb1 on /media/john/dropbox4 type fuseblk (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,default_permissions,allow_other,blksize=4096,uhelper=udisks2)

Comment: guillermo chamorro: under edit mount options, User Session Defauls is selected everything else is grayed out. Any idea for how to setup non default options to have a consistent mount point?

Comment: Are you using dropbox? dropbox supports only ext4 under linux. If you are using dropbox, remove it from your startup-applications, reboot and see if you can mount the drive manually and if you can use the mount-options in the GUI then.

Comment: Add it to the fstab using the UUID and it will always mount to the same location every time you plug it in.

Comment: not using dropbox, but rather my external hard drive is called dropbox

Comment: rtaft, can you explain "fstab using the UUID".  New to ubuntu.

Comment: rtaft, i tried to add an entry in fstab and it cause ubuntu to not boot.  So hints at what to fill in would be nice.

Comment: `getfacl /media/$USER`  please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

User interface way to solve, no messing with command line:

1. Click Activities, search for program "disks", launch
2. Click on the hard drive
3. Click the gears under the "volumes image"
4. Select Edit mount options
5. Disable "User Session Defaults"
6. Enable "Mount at system startup"
7. Enable "Show in user interface"
8. Enter a value for "mount point" like "mnt/dropbox"
9. click ok
10. reboot

Now the disk is always available at mnt/dropbox.

Comment: Nice answer. I've used it for Backintime to backup my files on an external hard drive in /media